# How do I set an element's height to 100% viewport width

Tags: css, viewport-units

I am trying to set an elements height to equal the viewport width.
How can this be achieved? (taking the following fiddle as an example)...

https://jsfiddle.net/minlare/0hnn7pfy/

```
body{margin:0;}    
div{min-height: 100vw;}
```

Mismatch between height and width only occurs when a scrollbar is present.

I need to account for the cases where the scrollbar might be present, keeping a *square* format for my div.

Comment: why doesn't what you've fiddled work?

Comment: So what is wrong? Your div is same height as width

Comment: mismatch between height and width only occurs when a scrollbar is present, how to avoid this?

Comment: use height instead of min-height

Comment: Do you want/need the scrollbar to be present? If not, just add `overflow: hidden` to your css. If you do, then you'll have your work cut out for you...

Comment: the scrollbar can be present or not

Comment: Are you saying the only way to achieve this is to check for a scrollbar (with js) and remove the scrollbar width when present?

Comment: yup, that's what i'm saying... if it's true or not, i'm not sure. :)

Comment: [**check this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bc7vz56L/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
body{
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
div{
  background: lightblue;
  height: 100vw;
  width:100vw;
}
```

this removes the scrolling and gives the same width and height to the `div`

Comment: Does not work, the height of the element should be equal to the viewports width - not the height of the viewport

Comment: I have tried this, it means there is a bleed of scrollbar width to the right of the element - for centered text it is off center

Answer (score 0):

You have to set its height:100%; and html,body height:100%;

```css
html,body{height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;}
.box{height:100%;position:relative;background-color:grey}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Does not work, the height of the element should be equal to the viewports width

Comment: Try to resize the window and the height of elements adjusts .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/minlare/owa63rjn/ - height and width are not equal (unless i'm missing something?)

Comment: Ahh sorry now i understood the question

Comment: you can see this jfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0hnn7pfy/3/ . That it checks height and width and it acts accordingle using jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using one of the appropriate among following javascript methods:

```
window.screen.height    
window.screen.availHeight
document.documentElement.clientHeight   
document.documentElement.offsetHeight   
document.documentElement.scrollHeight
```

This link may be useful: http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/

Answer (score -1):

use the meta tag 
add this in your

```
<META NAME="viewport" CONTENT="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
```

and in your css

```
@-ms-viewport{
  width: device-width;
  height: device-height;
}
```

Comment: does not work for me, height is still greater than viewport width